# How does the bounds marking works in vscode plugins?

Tags: plugins, vscode-extensions, liskov-substitution-principle

```
public void doSomething() {

}
```

If I keep my cursor at the open-brace token ({) the vscode will highlight the matching close-brace token (}). How does this happen?